# Slow response from getcomposer.org breaking deployments

Tags: composer-php

It seems that getcomposer.org is responding very slowly today. This is breaking deployments that have reasonable timeouts for various steps. Is there a fallback or alternate address?

Comment: This is why you should really be using `composer.lock` files and `composer install` instead of `composer update` for deployments. The `.lock` file contains the exact versions (including their Github etc. URLs) so it doesn't have to be looked up.

Comment: Just checked - we are using composer install, not composer update.

`composer.phar self-update`

`composer --working-dir=... --optimize-autoloader install`

Comment: Back in business now. I guess root cause on the site was resolved. Would still like to understand how I can guard against this in the future. Using capistrano - I'm guessing based on @ceejayoz comment that it must be the self-update that was failing.

Comment: Do you have the `composer.lock` file included with deployments? `install` will use it, but some folks `.gitignore` it for some reason in their version control.

Comment: Yes composer.lock is under SC and is deployed to the hosts.

Comment: I'd guess your theory on the self-update is the right one, then. If you can make that an optional step with a short timeout it might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getcomposer.org should not impact your deployment, however if getcomposer.org is slow, most likely packagist.org is also affected, which hosts the package information.

If you directly use the projects from Packagist, your deployments not only depend on packagist.org being up, and available, but the hosting site for the projects you depend on (most likely Github or Bitbucket). This is probably not the best option, if it's important for you to be able to deploy independently of the status of these sites.

You can run a local Satis instance to avoid depending on packagist.org. If you want to stop depending on Github or Bitbucket as well, then you could host a private copy of the repositories for your dependencies, and provide your private repositories in your private Satis instance you can be self sufficient and disable using Packagist in your composer.json.

If you have a local Satis instance, you have to update it periodically to be able to update your dependencies. If you self host the repositories as well, then you will need to pull from upstream and update Satis before you are able to run composer update.

For information on Satis check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md.